# Endpoint contract response from PAB

Tags: plutus, plutus-starter, plutus-pab

Is there a way to return values that are not the unit in JSON form from an endpoint?

Currently, any successful endpoint call over HTTP returns `"[]"`.

The only way we have to debug content is on the PAB side, from which we can read logs.

Does this have to do with the final parameter of the `Contract w s e a` where a is generally the unit in most starter PAB code?

According to the docs, a is a semigroup. If we return some type there we still don't get a result from the PAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, it's not possible to return a value different to unit because the `endpoint` response always returns unit `()` [check here in endpoint line](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-pab/src/Plutus/PAB/Webserver/API.hs#L43)

Here is the call to `endpoint`:

`:<|> "endpoint" :> Capture "endpoint-name" String :> ReqBody '[JSON] JSON.Value :> Description "Call an endpoint." :> Post '[JSON] ()`

`Post` receives a `JSON` with `JSON.Value` value and returns a `JSON` with a `()` value.

Anyway, you can use `status` to debug and read logs, which returns `ContractInstanceClientState` including:

- `observableState`
- `logs`
- `lastLogs`

You call `status` in this way:
`/api/contract/instance/<contract-instance-id>/status`